# Unable to execute .cpp files in CLion using the console and make commands (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, makefile, command, clion

I got a bunch of .cpp files in a project in the CLion IDE which I would like run in order to see what the code is actually doing. The makefile looks like this:

```
## ptp test
run-ptp: create-ptp
    ./systems/ptpTest/build/ptpTest
```

To run the code I went to the console and went to the project root directory which contains the .cpp files I like to run. When I enter the make command "make run-ptp" on the console it returns:

The "make" command is either misspelled or could not be found.

What could possibly be the reason for this to happen and how can I make it work, so that I can run the .cpp files via console and make command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sane way of running makefiles on Windows is from MSYS2.

Answer (score 2):

It means either (a) you don't have make installed on your system, or (b) you have it installed but the directory it's installed into is not on your `PATH` so your shell can't find it, or (c) you have it installed and it's on your `PATH` but it's installed using a different name than `make` such as `gmake` or something like that.

Since you haven't described what operating system you're using nor how you installed make on it that's the best we can do.